# Convert inflated layout into a bitmap android

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I am inflating a layout and converting it into and then i will share it using the as usual intents.

inflating the layout using -

```
LayoutInflater inflater2 = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        qr_sheetview = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.dummy_layout, mainlayout, false);
```

I tried three methods -

1. convert the inflated view into bitmap using this method

> qr_sheetview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
>                   qr_sheetview.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
>   View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
>                           View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
>                   qr_sheetview.layout(0, 0, qr_sheetview.getMeasuredWidth(), qr_sheetview.getMeasuredHeight());
>                   qr_sheetview.buildDrawingCache(true);
>   sharedbmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(qr_sheetview.getDrawingCache());

But using this method my layout gets shrinked and overlapped.

width was 1107 height was 448

I am using Framelayout as rootlayout and relative layout for inner views.

2. Second method i am using is this - >

   sharedbmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(qr_sheetview.getWidth(), qr_sheetview.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                   canvas = new Canvas(sharedbmap);
                   qr_sheetview.draw(canvas);

in this method error occurred : height and width must be > 0

using this also gives me the same error

```
qr_sheetview.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        sharedbmap = loadBitmapFromView(qr_sheetview);

                        shareBitmap(adjustOpacity(sharedbmap), "temporary");

                    }
                });
```

3. the third method is this - >

   public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {

   ```
           int specWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0 /* any */, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
           v.measure(specWidth, specWidth);

           Log.d("TAG", "height" + v.getMeasuredHeight());
           Log.d("TAG", "width" + v.getMeasuredWidth());

           Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
           Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
           v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
           v.draw(c);

           return b;
       }
   ```

in this i am getting the same result as in first.

the Layout is ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainqrlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout001"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:text="Some text"
                android:textColor="#212121"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appname"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logomain" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout003"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout001">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/qrimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/qr_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/kj_qr_logo_svg" />




        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout003"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vpaname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="kdvkjadsfkasmd"
                android:textColor="#212121" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qr_vpa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/vpaname"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="skdmfkjasdf"
                android:textColor="#444444" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/qr_vpa"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="ckasfdowmdmwkmdwkdmkwmdklmekld \n sdafasdfasdfaasdf"
                android:textColor="#727272" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/companyname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/companyname"
                android:textColor="#727272"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: "But using this method my layout gets shrinked and overlapped" -- then presumably there is a problem with your layout. You might consider posting the layout and the code that you are using to inflate that layout. Make sure your layout's root is not a `RelativeLayout` (use anything else). BTW, of your techniques, #3 seems the closest to what I would be trying.

Comment: why not Relative layout i mean previously i was using Linear layout and the result was as desired. But as my layout is little bit complex i think relative is best for me. how can i make this work using Relative layout

Comment: Wrap the `RelativeLayout` in something else, like a `FrameLayout`. `RelativeLayout` only works when it knows what its parent container is.

Comment: i have added the layout... please help...

Comment: i have also added how i am inflating the layout

Comment: What is `mainlayout`? If you switch to `inflate(R.layout.dummy_layout, null)`, do you have better results?

Comment: i did that previously but in vain.

Comment: and if i am using the Linear Layout as parent layout. the bitmap is not fullscreen... there is black on top and bottom of the bitmap